# Error "object 'res' not found" when trying to run mixpanelGetProfiles()

Tags: r, mixpanel

Tried running the following code to query MixPanel API using RMixpanel package.  However, I get the following error:

> Error in mixpanelGetData(account, "engage/", args, data = TRUE,
>   verbose = verbose) :   object 'res' not found

```
require(RMixpanel)
account = mixpanelCreateAccount('hidden', 
                                token = 'hidden', 
                                key = 'hidden',
                                secret = 'hidden')
profiles = mixpanelGetProfiles(account, select = c("Group Count", "DM 
Count", "Relationship Count","Lifetime members added"),maxPage = 
100,verbose = TRUE)
```

Above code should query the Mixpanel Formatted Data Export API.  Couldn't find anyone else talking about this issue.

Comment: Did you try to execute the call without setting the parameter `select` ?